# Any plants that work as a racoon repellent?

Tags: pest-control, pests

I saw 4 raccoons in my vegetable garden,  doing what they do best with people's gardens. 
Please let me know if I could plant anything in or around at the borders to my vegetable garden that would work as a racoon repellent. 
I don't want to use chemicals.

Comment: Plant snipers, or aggressive dogs.  Not much else is going to work. You can have a fun time trying to create an electric fence they won't figure out how not to get shocked by.

Comment: What are plant snippers and I don't want to build an electric fence it will be I will be getting electrocuted probably most of the time if I plant mint leaves wouldn't make the raccoons

Comment: Snipers, one "p". You plant them in a nice, deep hole with a thermos full of coffee (or tea), some rations, a rifle and ammunition - it's inadvisable to fill in with any dirt, as it makes them grumpy. Translation - shoot the raccoons - they are certainly not going to be impeded by mint. You can either kill them, or you can attempt to keep them out - they happen to be **very** hard to keep out, so shooting is far more efficient.

Comment: I think [How do I prevent raccoons from eating my corn?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/how-do-i-prevent-raccoons-from-eating-my-corn) covers most of the possible territory for this question.

Comment: Joseph-thanks so much for caring about both the plants and the backyard visitors. It can be tough to grow things with those gorgeous guys around, but it's awesome that you want to do that rather than hurting them. I hope you get some help and find something that works. As @stormy said, thanks again, and let us know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a wire fence around your garden.  There's 'field fencing' with smaller openings at the bottom that get a bit larger towards the top. Once these little brainiacs have found what they want, you have to get fencing.  I have a problem with them as well as bunnies.  Well, not any more.  My greenhouse and outdoor garden all have this 'bunny fence' installed.  Have to dig a 6" trench so they can't dig underneath.  You might have to find a mesh to pull over the top as well.  Bunnies don't hop over but raccoon (sp) are far more intelligent!! I adore raccoon!!  Bunnies, too...well, all animals.  Trick is to live in harmony.  Killing anything NEVER SOLVES A PROBLEM.  Never.  Tide rolls out, tide rolls in.  Lots more to take their place.  Poison...interestingly...actually causes animals such as rodents, raccoon, squirrels, bunnies...to have larger litters. This fence is inexpensive, easy to install and you'll be able to sleep at night!!  You could also FEED your raccoon somewhere distant from your garden...stuff like your vegetable scraps.  I know others are flipping out with this but I feed bunnies, raccoon, raven and deer with stuff that would normally go into my compost and I live in total harmony.  I also have dogs (I would never allow to chase and kill) but the fact their smell and presence is obvious, makes a huge difference.

Comment: No flipping out here-I love your attitude! We kill nothing, feed everything, and enjoy the beauty of every creature. In fact, we've only ever seen one raccoon at a time, but last night there was a whole family-mama, papa and three youngsters-frolicking in the trees and tipping over bird feeders! Today we put out a tub of water in case they might be thirsty after emptying the birdbaths, but it looked deep enough to drown the chipmunks, so we won't risk it :)

Comment: Oh!!  I LOVE you!!!  Dang, I am impressed with your thinking...maybe our species WILL make it...grin!!  That water is important but you are so correct about keeping a big tub of water around.  I've found chipmunks, baby birds learning to fly in my horse troughs.  Not cool.  I always throw a log or branch that they can escape to...shallow bowls just need more maintenance.  If only more people were like you...thank you, thank you!

Comment: Found someone who uses Repel All or Repel something or other that they said they thought worked!!  They said the smell is horrid...I am sorta into good smells...bad smells ruin any ambiance of a garden.  Dissipates after awhile so worth trying if desperate.   Let us know if you find something that works for you and your 'neighborhood'...again, Thank YOU!!

Comment: OH very funny.  Here is the comment I was alluding too, my face is a bit red...!

Comment: stormy, I'm confused-my normal state-about which comment you were alluding too. I thought it was partly for me, telling me you loved me, a huge compliment that made me so happy! :))  You're the awesome, inspirational one! I love YOU and wish there were more people like YOU! You're a friend, cheerleader and teacher, and make us feel like our gardens really matter to you! If it wasn't meant for me, I'm the one with the red face, and am sorry!!!! No need to respond, just glad I got a chance to publicly thank you for loving ALL creatures! Cool idea to put a branch in the water :).

Answer (score 2):

There is actually an all natural alternative that I have found to be extremely helpful. There are no harmful chemicals used, however a putrid odor will accompany the use for a day or two. The product is called [Repels-All](http://www.gardeners.com/buy/repels-all-animal-repellent/38-534.html).

I only do organic (natural) gardening for my family and this stuff has saved my strawberries, blueberries and tomatoes. Again, the stench is enough to drive some humans away but lessens after a few days. I prefer liquid applications, but the granules can be easily dissolved in a water solution.

Comment: This stuff works in your experience?  Huh.  I will look into this stuff...it would be nice to have to power to encourage harmony by just adding a foul smell.  Thanks, Charlotte!

Comment: Yes. I applied an initial dose ("heavier" than recommended, but since I can tolerate the stench it was not a bother). We reapply after every heavy rains and have had great success. If you check out [their website](http://www.bonide.com/best_solution/index.html) you can read up on their other products. If you read the reviews on from the initial answer post you'd have see that most of the dissatisfied customers were dealing with deer. They have a separate line of products specifically for deer and rabbits. I hope it works for you too!